# Setting keys in model relationships in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm pulling data from a table called Visits and I want to get room information as well. The cell Visits.room_id references Rooms.id, however, CakePHP is using Visits.id instead which I'm assuming is because it's the primary key.

Here are the tables

```
Visits - id is primary key. I even tried setting room_id as a foreign key when creating the table
id    |   guest_id    |    room_id   |   arrival_date   |    departure_date

Rooms - id is prmary key. 
id  |   description   |   max_occupancy
```

So basically it's doing the following in a query

```
where Visits.id = Rooms.id
```

Instead of

```
where Visits.room_id = Rooms.id
```

In my Visit Model I have the following

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'room' => array(
        'className' => 'room',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);
```

And here's an example of a query from the VisitsController

```
$visits = $this->paginate('Visit', array(
            'arrival_date >=' => $date
            )
        );                  
        $this->set(compact('visits'));
```

Is there any way I can tell CakePHP to use Visit.room_id instead of Visit.id?

Comment: public $hasOne = array(
    'Room' => array(
        'className' => 'Room',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `Visit` model

```
public $belongsTo = array('Room');
```

instead of `hasOne`.

Maybe this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'room' => array(
        'className' => 'room',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    )
);
```

is not set correctly. I see you are sticking to conventions, so that relation can be summarize in a one-liner like

```
public $hasOne = array('Room');
```

That's actually the advantage of conventions, you don't need to configure as much for it to work.

(and in Room Model, do `public $belongsTo = array('Visit');` to have it the other way around in case you need it)

Now, getting that out of the way, rethink your relations. [Check the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone), if Visit hasOne Room, then the tables should be

```
Visit                    Room
-----                    ----
id | etc                 id | visit_id
```

In `hasOne`

> hasOne: the other model contains the foreign key.

So to keep your tables like you have them now, the relations should be `Visit belongsTo Room` and  `Room hasOne Visit` (or it may have many, depends on you).

(PD. I'm assuming cake v2.x)

Comment: Now it's looking for Room.visit_id    Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Room.visit_id' in 'on clause'